# Any idea why this simple program (creating powershell session) taking so much memory (~150 MB)?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, c#-3.0, powershell-2.0

I am fairly new to powershell programming. I am creating remote sessions to execute some commands programmatically. However its consuming so much memory (in the order of ~150 to 200 MB). ANd more sessions, its more memory.

Can you please help me figure out the issue?

1. What is the culprit?
2. How can i fix it?

Observations:
1. After executing CreateRunSpace command, its consuming around 3MB.

---

Someone faced the same issue with creating runspaces:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/69ccce9d-4696-4886-a5d0-5d2d2e1e4e6d

"Possible PowerShell Runspace Handle Leak"

### Still investigating to find the answer though...

Removing pssession made the runspace to release the handles and fixed the memory leak. Its now toggling between ~30 to 40MB.

---

Thank you!

(FYI - referenced System.Management.Automation.dll)

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int success = 0;
            int fails = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
                //After this the memory will be incremented by ~3Mb in taskmanager
                rs.Open();
                using (Pipeline pl = rs.CreatePipeline())
                {
                    Command cmd = new Command("new-pssession");
                    pl.Commands.Add(cmd);
                    var retval = pl.Invoke();
                    if (retval.Count > 0)
                    {
                        success++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fails++;
                    }
                    pl.Stop();
                }
                rs.Close();
                rs = null;
            }
            GC.Collect();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "~15o to 200"? Do you mean "~150MB to 200MB"?

Comment: You probably have a memory leak somewhere. I would suggest looking into some profiling tools, like [ANTS Memory Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_content=brand_aware&utm_campaign=antsmemoryprofiler&gclid=CJC-rZmjrKwCFQ8q7AodqSjpZA) and [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/).

Comment: There is a leak. Please look at this: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winserverpowershell/thread/69ccce9d-4696-4886-a5d0-5d2d2e1e4e6d

Comment: any solution about it ? any sample full sourcecode ?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like removing-pssession from the runspace released the memory handles and fixed the leak. Now its taking ~35MB.

```
int success = 0;
int fails = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
{
    Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
    rs.Open();
    using (Pipeline pl = rs.CreatePipeline())
    {
        Command cmd = new Command("new-pssession");
        pl.Commands.Add(cmd);
        var retval = pl.Invoke();
        if (retval.Count > 0)
        {
            success++;
            PSSession Session = (PSSession)retval[0].BaseObject;
            using (Pipeline pl2 = rs.CreatePipeline())
            {
                Command cmd2 = new Command("remove-pssession");
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("Id", Session.Id);
                pl2.Commands.Add(cmd2);
                var retval2 = pl2.Invoke();
                pl2.Stop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fails++;
        }
        pl.Stop();
    }
    rs.Close();
    rs = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Runspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.runspaces.runspace%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) object are Disposable, is it the same if you code :

```
using (Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
{
}
```

Comment: It is recommended to call Close instead of Dispose if the class offers the Close method. Both methods do the same thing, especially if this is a Framework class. Therefore, his code is fine.

Comment: Yes, it doesnt have affect. Its the same.

Comment: @AMissico actually, the Dispose pattern must ensure everything is cleaned up, so calling `Close()` is not mandatory if the class has been implemented correctly.

Comment: @IgorBrejc - Nearly all Microsoft documentation that I have found recommends calling Close before calling Dispose. Any implementation of the Dispose pattern will call Close before disposing. Search Microsoft .NET source code for numerous examples.

Comment: @AMissico exactly my point :). Why would you need to call Close() explicitly if it's covered by the Dispose pattern? It actually destroys the usefulness of using() block, since you need to embed an additional try-final block inside to guarantee Close() is called. What would be the benefit?

Comment: @AMissico MS explains here that "Close()" is just a more appropriate name for Dispose in certain domains: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: If you object cannot be opened again then Close calls Dispose which calls Dispose(true). If your object can be opened again, the Dispose calls Close followed by Dispose(true). Search Microsoft .NET source code for numerous examples. The class implementor does this, not the programmer.

Comment: Using directive assume that the object created is properly disposed after usage -> {}. It's not so important for most .NET object which will be disposed when garbage collector vill see no reference and need memory.  But for objects on the top of COM (AD) or DataBases, or Network it may be more important to control when the "conections" are released. On the theorical point of view Close and Dispose  assume to different target but in real life it depends on implementation. Just don't forget that Dispose comes from an interface (IDisposable) it's more "object" than Close (procedural)